# Suppress Sections in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

What is the use of suppress in Crystal Reports?

Is it possible to delete a section (page footer) in crystal report?

If yes, then what is the difference between Suppress and Delete?

Answer (score 4):

Surpressing can be used in formulas, to allow the developer to surpress a section if a certain citeria is met. Or you can surpress the detail of the report if you wish to show a summary report.

You can surpress the page footer.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide or suppress any section that you want.  Hide allows for drill-down.  Suppressing a section hides it and prevents drill-down.

Bare minimum, you need a report header, page header, details, page footer, and report footer sections.  These can not be deleted.

You can additional sections of a given type by right-clicking the desired section and choosing 'Insert section below'.  The name of the section will append a letter, starting at 'A' to the name to indicate multiple sections of the same type.  If there are more than one section of a given type, then all but the last of these can be deleted.

Adding grouping adds a corresponding group header and footer sections.  These behave the same way that I've discussed.  Groups can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Suppress leaves the section in the report. In addition, if you have formulas in that section that are set to execute WhilePrintingRecords, they will run, though they won't display results.

Answer (score 1):

Delete a section means removing it from the report. Suppress a report means hide the section when viewing or printing the report. This is important when you want to only hide a section under some conditions.